# select max(case when convert(datetime2(0),DATEFROMPARTS(1998,05,30)) > GETDATE() -1 then 'Y' else 'N' end )

Tags: sql-server

Can anyone help me in explaining this query? I know the functions of each commands used in it.

But I do want to know like how does this result me with either `y` or `n` and how does max condition work on strings.

```
SELECT
    MAX(CASE 
        WHEN CONVERT(datetime2(0), DATEFROMPARTS(1998, 05, 30)) > GETDATE() - 1 
        THEN 'Y' 
            ELSE 'N' 
        END)
```

Comment: Max over a set of strings will return the latest string in alphabetic order, so if you have a sets of 'Y' and 'N', it will always return a 'Y' if there is at least one 'Y' on the set, or 'N' if all the values are 'N'.

Comment: Can you please use the form of a question for your title? Maybe change it to "Can anyone help me understand this SQL query?" or something similar.